# Angular ng build fails on "Cannot find module 'worker_threads'" error

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My current situation is this. I am stuck using Alpine 3.7 (currently customer states this cannot be upgraded).

This limits me to Node.js version of: 10.19.0
Which limits me to npm version of: 6.13.4
Which limits me to Angular CLI of: 11.2.19

I am trying to deploy using Jenkins a simple Angular Docker build.

Current I receive the error:

```
+ ng build -c dev
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'
```

I have searched up and down on how to resolve this and cannot seem to find any detail as the easiest solution is just to upgrade Nodejs (which I cannot).

The relevant portion of my Jenkins file is as follows:

```
sh "apk add --update npm"
sh "/usr/bin/env node --experimental-worker"
sh "npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.19"
sh "ng build -c dev"
sh "docker build -t 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/x/x-x:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -f Dockerfile ."
```

I would assume the second line would correct this issue, but it has not.

Comment: If you try to build on your machine do the job fail?

Comment: It will work on my machine, but that is because my local version of nodejs is at 18.14.2.

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` file to the question?